# Cannot read property 'show' of undefined with $mdToast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm really struggling with this issue and I don't know what the matter is...

I'm going to leave out a lot of code, but this is essentially the jist of it... Based off the [Angular material design guidelines](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast) this *should* work. I can't figure out for the life of me why it doesn't.

When I run the code I simply get an error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Main">
<!-- some stuff here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<div ng-click="executeToast()">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('MainController', [
        'MainService',
        'MainDirective',
        'ngMaterial', 
        'ngMessages',
        'ngSanitize'
    ])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', '$sce', '$mdToast', function($scope, Main, $sce, $apply, $rootScope, $mdToast) {
      $scope.executeToast() = function() {
           $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({
              hideDelay: 3000,
              position: 'top left',
              content: 'testing',
              toastClass: 'success'
            }));
      }
}]);
```

Any thoughts or possible solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of mistakes you made here :

1, In dependency injection sequence must be same, check more [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

2, No need to pass `$apply` as a dependency,

Try this

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$mdToast','$sce', function($scope, $rootScope, $mdToast, $sce) {
      $scope.executeToast() = function() {
           $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({
              hideDelay: 3000,
              position: 'top left',
              content: 'testing',
              toastClass: 'success'
            }));
```

Comment: Yes! That worked.. so do I not need the other dependencies I have listed?